# Filtering div's based on checkbox value

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, filter

I wont bother with posting my jquery because I'm pretty sure it is all nonsense considering it doesn't cause any errors but still doesn't do anything...

```
<h3>Candidate Experience</h3>

<div class="search_box">
<input type="checkbox" name="3year" id="3yearexp" value="1"> 3+ Years <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="5year" id="5yearexp" value="2"> 5+ Years <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="7year" id="7yearexp" value="3"> 7+ Years <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="10year" id="10yearexp" value="4"> 10+ Years <br>
</div>

<h3><br>Candidate Salary</h3>

<div class="search_box">
<input type="checkbox" name="3039" value="s29"> less than £29,999<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="3039" value="s3039"> £30,000 - £39,999 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="4059" value="s4059"> £40,000 - £59,999 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="6079" value="s6079"> £60,000 - £79,999 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="80plus" value="80plus"> £80,000 + <br>
</div>





<div class="talent_result_wrapper" data-experience="10yearexp" data-salary="s6079">
<ul>
<li><strong>Talent ID:  </strong>100007</li>
<li><strong>Resides:  </strong>London</li>
<li><strong>Salary Required:  </strong>£67000</li>
<li><strong>Experience:  </strong>10 Years </li>
<li><strong>Industy:  </strong>24</li>
<li><strong>Specialism:  </strong>24</li>
</ul>
<div>
<br>
<br> 

<div class="talent_result_wrapper" data-experience="5yearexp" data-salary="s3039">
<ul>
<li><strong>Talent ID:  </strong>100006</li>
<li><strong>Resides:      </strong>London</li>
<li><strong>Salary Required:  </strong>£35000</li>
<li><strong>Experience:  </strong>5 Years </li>
<li><strong>Industy:  </strong>24</li>
<li><strong>Specialism:  </strong>15</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use the checkboxes to filter out results. I've been googling this for days but i'm still pretty new to jquery so I'm really struggling.
Basically if I tick the 5 years experience checkbox, it should show the second result, likewise if I click the 10 years one it should show the first, or if I have both it should show both.

Similarly it would need to work with the salary, so if I checked the 30k -39k box, it should show the second result, and if i checked the 10 years and 30k - 39k it should show nothing.

Does this make sense?

I've created a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/MCam435/hpej8/

I've been trying to recreate something similar to this fiddle, but all i've managed to do is hide the entire content of my page!! http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/d2v4Q/

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the values of the checkboxes

instead of `1, 2, 3, 4`

do it like `value="10yearexp"` etc. then we can do this:

```
$(".search_box input[type=checkbox]").click( function(e){
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        $(".talent_result_wrapper").show();
    } else {
        $(".talent_result_wrapper").hide();
        $("div[data-experience='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
    }


    //added below shows all when nothing is checked!
    var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
    if(n === 0){
        $(".talent_result_wrapper").show();
    }

});
```

If it was up to me I would have a lot of changes but its not so anyway the code above is incomplete and there is more efficient ways to achieve what you need.

**Edit:**

Updated my answer its cleaner and shorter + it shows all elements when nothing is ticked

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hpej8/13/)

Comment: Thank you. Have just tried this, it's similar to how I was doing it, however it filters out both results. It's the same problem I had before, at it doesn't show everything again when I untick. (updated the fiddle).

Comment: Pst @Mcam435 check my update it works for all elements as long as you change the value to the `data-experience` + if all is untick it shows everything again.

Comment: Thanks, that's working. Doesn't unhide everything but it's closer than anything I have! To get this working on salary as well, would it be best to add the code as a completely new codeblock, or put it within this code? P.S, nice name + avatar :)

Comment: Yes you can make it into a completely new codeblock, you can even turn it into a simple function on click for all checkboxes, but again if it was up to me I would make a lot of changes to the code to make it even more simple. But atleast this would give you an idea on what to do P.S, i know right? ;D BTW check this if it helped! Cheers!

Comment: @Mcam435 check updated demo OR the codeblock I added a few lines that when nothing is ticked everything will show

Comment: Ah ha yes, that's awesome thank you. I just need to work out why it's not working on my actual page now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/LjY6v/2/). Its not completely done. But you will get an idea on how to do it.

```
$('input[data-exp], input[data-sal]').on('click', function(){
    if(this.checked)
    {
        var exp = $(this).attr('data-exp');
        var sal = $(this).attr('data-sal');
        alert(exp + sal);
        $('.talent_result_wrapper').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('data-experience') == exp || $(this).attr('data-salary') == sal)
            {
                $(this).show();
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that i have added attributes data-exp and data-sal to input elements because i did not see a uniformity in your style. You have used id and name elements to hold values in experience inputs and name and value elements in salary inputs. I changed them only for convenience. You can still do it with them.

Comment: I get an error on the fiddle saying undefined? Sorry yes I know the inputs are a bit messy. It's a desperate attempt at a prototype!

Comment: Yes you are bound to get 1 undefined value. If understand the code you  will see that i am checking for both salary and experience in a single  click handler with an || condition. When u click an input it will either be salary filter or experience filter. so u can safely ignore the other. I left the alert box in the fiddle just to show u that. Hope this helps.

Comment: and like i said i have not worked on the logic much. Just thought will show u how this can be done in jquery. So if u meddle with the if condition you will get it right at some point.

Comment: Ok yes sorry I see. I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but the second result (10006) doesn't seem to show up at all on any of the checkboxes?